PHP PDO error - SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
could someone have a look at my code and help me figure out what is causing the error in my PDO query.
The query works fine when I search by "Department", "Datarange", "Employer" and "Status". But when I search and there is data in the "name" field, it returns this error message.
Error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in /home/xyz/public_html/dir1/user3/user_lists.php:102 Stack trace: #0 /home/xyz/public_html/dir1/user3/user_lists.php(102): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/xyz/public_html/dir1/user3/user_lists.php on line 102

The line 102 in my code is:
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

My Code:
// Get org ID only from the array
$current_organisation_id = $current_organisation['current_organisation_id'];

// Initialize search parameters
$search_params = [
    'name' => trim(isset($_POST['search_name']) ? str_replace("'", "", $_POST['search_name']) : ''),
    'start_date_range' => isset($_POST['search_start_date']) ? $_POST['search_start_date'] : '',
    'status' => trim(isset($_POST['search_status']) ? str_replace("'", "", $_POST['search_status']) : ''),
    'employer' => trim(isset($_POST['search_employer']) ? str_replace("'", "", $_POST['search_employer']) : ''),
    'department' => trim(isset($_POST['search_department']) ? str_replace("'", "", $_POST['search_department']) : '')
];

// Parse date range if provided
$by_start_date_from = "";
$by_start_date_to = "";
if ($search_params['start_date_range'] != "") {
    $by_start_date_from = substr($search_params['start_date_range'], 6, 4) . "-" . substr($search_params['start_date_range'], 3, 2) . "-" . substr($search_params['start_date_range'], 0, 2);
    $by_start_date_to = substr($search_params['start_date_range'], 19, 4) . "-" . substr($search_params['start_date_range'], 16, 2) . "-" . substr($search_params['start_date_range'], 13, 2);
}


// Base SQL query
$sql = "SELECT 
    tb_users.id AS users_id, 
    tb_users.name AS users_name, 
    tb_users.surname AS users_surname, 
    tb_users.username AS users_username, 
    tb_users.password AS users_password, 
    tb_users.created AS users_created, 
    tb_users.active AS users_active, 
    tb_users.employer AS users_employer, 
    tb_users.department AS users_department, 
    tb_employer.id AS employer_id, 
    tb_employer.employer_name AS employer_name, 
    tb_departments.id AS department_id, 
    tb_departments.department_name AS department_name, 
    tb_user_organisation.user_id AS user_organisation_id, 
    tb_schedules.id AS schedule_id, 
    tb_schedules.schedule_name AS schedule_name 
FROM 
    tb_users 
    JOIN tb_user_organisation ON tb_users.id = tb_user_organisation.user_id 
    JOIN tb_employer ON tb_users.employer2 = tb_employer.id 
    JOIN tb_schedules ON tb_users.schedule_id = tb_schedules.id 
    JOIN tb_departments ON tb_users.department = tb_departments.id 
WHERE 
    tb_user_organisation.organisation_id = :current_organisation_id";


// Array to hold query conditions
$query_conditions = [];
$query_params = [':current_organisation_id' => $current_organisation_id];

// Loop through search parameters to build query conditions
if ($_POST) {
    if ($search_params['name'] != "") {
        $query_conditions[] = "(tb_users.name LIKE :name OR tb_users.surname LIKE :name)";
        $query_params[':name'] = "%" . $search_params['name'] . "%";
    }
    if ($by_start_date_from != "") {
        $query_conditions[] = "LEFT(tb_users.created, 10) >= :by_start_date_from";
        $query_params[':by_start_date_from'] = $by_start_date_from;
    }
    if ($by_start_date_to != "") {
        $query_conditions[] = "LEFT(tb_users.created, 10) <= :by_start_date_to";
        $query_params[':by_start_date_to'] = $by_start_date_to;
    }
    if ($search_params['status'] != "x") {
        $query_conditions[] = "tb_users.active = :status";
        $query_params[':status'] = $search_params['status'];
    }
    if ($search_params['employer'] != "x") {
        $query_conditions[] = "tb_employer.id = :employer";
        $query_params[':employer'] = $search_params['employer'];
    }
    if ($search_params['department'] != "x") {
        $query_conditions[] = "tb_users.department = :department";
        $query_params[':department'] = $search_params['department'];
    }
}

// Append conditions to the SQL query
if (!empty($query_conditions)) {
    $sql .= " AND " . implode(" AND ", $query_conditions);
}

$sql .= " ORDER BY tb_users.id DESC";
//echo $sql;

// Prepare and execute the query
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($query_params);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Add:
When I replace this line
$query_conditions[] = "(wt_users.name LIKE :name OR wt_users.surname LIKE :name)";

With this line:
 $query_conditions[] = "(wt_users.name LIKE :name)";

It fixes the error, but it stop searching for surname.

What does the query come out as and what parameters do you have? var_dump($sql, $query_params)... generally Invalid parameter number means you have more placeholders or values

Is the str_replace to avoid SQL injections also? If so that is not needed and may result in you getting incorrect results. I would remove it.

Getting that error on the fetch is unlikely, the line count is likely off as it should generate that during execute(). Dump the generated SQL and parameter list and verify that the parameters you're binding match the placeholders you're putting in the query.

I have added more relevant info at the bottom of my post.

You can't have :name palceholder twice. Use something like wt_users.name LIKE :name OR wt_users.surname LIKE :sname and set both sname and name.

@u_mulder If emulates are on it can be duplicated, no?

Are emulations on? Have you outputted the query and the parameters?

@u-mulder's solution was correct, I had to change the name of second placeholder:

u-mulder:
You can't have :name palceholder twice. Use something like
wt_users.name LIKE :name OR wt_users.surname LIKE :sname and set both
sname and name.

My solution:
$query_conditions[] = "(wt_users.name LIKE :name OR wt_users.surname LIKE :surname)";
$query_params[':name'] = "%" . $search_params['name'] . "%";
$query_params[':surname'] = "%" . $search_params['name'] . "%";

